# When sample size = 3, why this matrix is non-singular?

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, covariance, singularity

When sample size $n=3$ is the sufficient and necessary condition for the following matrix $T$ to be non-singular?

To be clear, assume $X_1, X_2, X_3\overset{i.i.d}{\sim}(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a 3 by 3 positive definite symmatrix covariance matrix. $S$ is sample covariance matrix assuming mean is zero, i.e. $S = (X_1X_1^T+X_2X_2^T+X_3X_3^T)/3=\begin{pmatrix}
  s_{11} & s_{12}& s_{13}\\ 
   s_{12} &  s_{22}&  s_{23}\\ 
   s_{13} &  s_{23}&  s_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$.

Why the following matrix is non-singular when $n=3$ and singular when $n<3$?
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12}& s_{13}& 0 & 0 & 0\\
s_{12} & s_{22}+s_{11}&s_{23}&s_{12}&s_{13}&0\\
s_{13} & s_{23}&s_{33}+s_{11}&0&s_{12}&s_{13}\\
0 & s_{12}&0&s_{22}&s_{23}&0\\
0&s_{13} &s_{12}&s_{23}&s_{22}+s_{33}&s_{23}\\
0&0&s_{13}&0&s_{23}&s_{33}
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Apparently, $T$ is made of by "stacking" $S$, for example, the principal submatrix of column 2,4,5 is $S$ (if removing diagonal terms $s_{11}$ and $s_{33}$ which are stacked from another principal submatrix of $S$).

---

I am trying to prove by contradiction. If it is singular, I was hoping to show that the columns of $S$ are linearly dependent. But I got stuck. I hope this can be approved in a general way.

Comment: Regarding "Can I say..." -- no, for a few reasons. (1) What does it mean for three *numbers* to be linearly independent? (2) There is no notion of linear independence that can be established by looking at just the left half of a matrix. If there was, you could fill the entire right half of the matrix with zeroes and that would somehow not matter, but that's clearly not the case. (To be clear: you *can* establish linear *de*pendence by looking at just the left half of a matrix, but you can't establish linear *in*dependence by doing the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, seemingly.

By noticing $T$ is a Hessian of $$\sum_{i=1}^p\omega_{.i}^TS\omega_{i.},$$
where $\omega_{.i}$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $\Omega = \Sigma^{-1}$.

This is a sum of strictly convex quadratic forms (given $n=3$). Hence its Hessian is positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

For the original question with $n=2$: by the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) the $3\times 3$ matrix $T$ has determinant
$$
\det(T)=\det(S)^2(s_{11}+s_{22}).
$$
This is equal to zero if $\det(S)=0$, or $s_{11}+s_{22}=0$.

For $n=3$, $\det(S)$ is again a factor, and we have
$$
\det(T)=\det(S)(s_{11}^2s_{22} + s_{11}^2s_{33} - s_{11}s_{12}^2 - s_{11}s_{13}^2 + s_{11}s_{22}^2 + 2s_{11}s_{22}s_{33}
+ s_{11}s_{33}^2 - s_{12}^2s_{22} - 2s_{12}s_{13}s_{23} - s_{13}^2s_{33} + s_{22}^2s_{33} - s_{22}s_{23}^2
 + s_{22}s_{33}^2 - s_{23}^2s_{33}).
$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I made edits. I was hoping to prove it in a general way.

Comment: Yes, in general, if $\det(S)=0$, then $\det(T)=0$.

Comment: $\det(S)\neq 0$ because $p=3$ and $n=3$. I am proving $\det(T)\neq 0$, in a general way.

Comment: $s_{11}$ and $s_{22}$ cannot be zero, because they are from a sample covariance matrix (assuming the random variable is not degenerate).

Comment: So you need more than just nonzero determinant of $S$. It is not enough to argue with "linearly dependent".

Comment: Thanks. But I am trying to argue $T$ is linearly **independent**.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. You want to argue by contradiction. You say "I am trying to prove by contradiction. If it is singular, I was hoping to show that the columns of S are **linearly dependent**. But I got stuck." So you assume that $T$ is singular. Then either $\det(S)=0$, a contradiction, **or** this polynomial in the $s_{ij}$ is zero. For **this** part you need the other assumptions. For example, for $n=2$ you need that $s_{11}+s_{22}\neq 0$.